# Creating an istream peeker

Tags: c++, stream

I want an `istream` that you can safely peek arbitrarily many characters from. This works as far as I can tell, but I am unsure if this is really "the right way" to do it since the iostream library is pretty cryptic to me.

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <vector>

class peekbuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* sbuf_;
    std::vector<char> data_;
    char ch; 
public:
    peekbuf(std::streambuf* s)
    : sbuf_(s)
    { } 

    std::vector<char> const& peek(int N) {
        data_.clear();
        data_.reserve(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            int next = sbuf_->sbumpc();
            if (next == traits_type::eof()) {
                break;
            }
            data_.push_back(next);
        }

        if (!data_.empty()) {
            setg(data_.data(), data_.data(), data_.data() + data_.size());
        }

        return data_;
    }   

protected:
    int_type underflow() override {
        ch = sbuf_->sbumpc();
        setg(&ch, &ch, &ch + 1); 
        return ch; 
    }   
};
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    peekbuf buf{std::cin.rdbuf()};
    std::cin.rdbuf(&buf);

    auto first5 = buf.peek(5);

    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << "Got " << s << '\n';

    std::cout << "Peeked: ";
    for (char c : first5) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Where:

```
$ echo 123456789 | ./a.out
```

yields:

```
Got 123456789
Peeked: 12345
```

Comment: I don;t have time write now (this weekend). But something feels wrong. When you set the underlying buffer with `setg(data_.data(), data_.data(), data_.data() + data_.size());` I would expect you to save the state of the current buffer so when you have finished reading your peeked data you can go back to the original buffer.

Comment: You don't need to go back to the original, you've just set the internal buffer to a new valid state.   The only downside here is, of course, that regular i/o buffers support "unget" which `setg` supports by setting the first two arguments nonequal.   You may find that this peek class interferes with operations of some parsers, etc.

Comment: @Toby_Speight I thought that the code in the question should not be edited after the question has been answered?

Answer (score 4):

This member needs a good comment:

> ```
>    char ch;
> ```

It's only used in one function, and there it is assigned before any other use, so it's easy to overlook that `setg()` retains a pointer to it, and to think its scope can be reduced to that one function.

Or we could use the existing vector to hold that character when we need it.

---

The constructor should be `explicit`, and `g++ -Weffc++` would like it to also initialize the vector.  (That's perhaps overzealous, but pacifying it lets us get some more useful warnings from that option.)

We have a pointer data member, but it's safe to share that between instances.  I (and `-Weffc++`) would appreciate an indication that we have actually thought about that:

```
// we don't own the pointer, so it's okay to copy
peekbuf(const peekbuf& b) = default;
peekbuf& operator=(const peekbuf& b) = default;
```

A better solution would be to recognise that `sbuf_` must not be null, and so work with a reference instead of a pointer.

---

`peek()` should probably take a `std::size_t` argument, rather than `int`.

`int next` probably ought to be `int_type next` - or better, `auto next`.  I'd like to see the narrowing to `char` be explicit:

```
        data_.push_back(static_cast<char>(next));
```

We have a **bug**, in that if we `peek()` before we have read everything from the preceding `peek()`, we lose input.  Instead of clearing `data_`, we need to be a bit more careful.  We need to take care that the subsequent `peek()` might request *less* than we have saved in the vector, or more.

Returning a reference to `data_` could be risky, since it may be modified before the caller uses it (e.g. if we write `auto const& first5 = buf.peek(5);`).

My improved version copies the unread peeked characters (I'm not convinced it's safe to `assign` from a subset of a vector's own elements, and we can't use `erase()` because vector iterators don't have to be pointers):

```
std::vector<char> peek(std::size_t n)
{
    auto unread = std::vector<char>(gptr(), egptr());
    data_ = std::move(unread);
    data_.reserve(n);
    for (auto i = data_.size();  i < n;  ++i) {
        auto next = sbuf_->sbumpc();
        if (next == traits_type::eof()) {
            break;
        }
        data_.push_back(static_cast<char>(next));
    }

    if (!data_.empty()) {
        setg(data_.data(), data_.data(), data_.data() + data_.size());
    }

    return n < data_.size()
        ? std::vector<CharT>(data_.begin(), data_.begin() + n)
        : data_;
}
```

---

There's a **bug** in `underflow()`: it fails to pass through EOF properly, as it narrows to `char` and returns that narrowed `char` rather than the original value.  Easily fixed:

```
int_type underflow() override
{
    auto result = sbuf_->sbumpc();
    char ch = static_cast<char>(result); // if it's eof, it's never read anyway
    setg(&ch, &ch, &ch + 1);
    return result;
}
```

---

In the main function, we have:

> ```
> std::cout << "Peeked: ";
> for (char c : first5) {
>     std::cout << c;
> }
> std::cout << '\n';
> ```

That's more clearly and succinctly written as:

```
std::cout << "Peeked: "
          << std::string(first5.begin(), first5.end())
          << '\n';
```

We might consider using a `std::string` instead of vector throughout - it's probably more useful to callers.

---

Overall enhancement - consider making the class generic, so it can work with wide streams, too:

```
template<typename CharT, typename Traits= std::char_traits<CharT>>
class peekbuf : public std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>
{
    using streambuf = std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>;
```

---

## Full rewrite

```
template<typename streambuf>
class peekbuf : public streambuf
{
    using typename streambuf::char_type;
    using typename streambuf::traits_type;
    using typename streambuf::int_type;
    using string = std::basic_string<char_type, traits_type>;

    static constexpr auto eof = streambuf::traits_type::eof();

    using streambuf::gptr;
    using streambuf::egptr;
    using streambuf::setg;

    streambuf& sbuf;           // underlying input buffer
    string data = {};

public:
    explicit peekbuf(streambuf& s)
        : sbuf{s}
    { }

    string peek(std::size_t n)
    {
        auto unread = string{gptr(), egptr()};
        data = std::move(unread);
        data.reserve(n);
        while (data.size() < n) {
            auto next = sbuf.sbumpc();
            if (next == eof) {
                break;
            }
            data.push_back(static_cast<char_type>(next));
        }

        if (!data.empty()) {
            setg(data.data(), data.data(), data.data() + data.size());
        }

        return n < data.size()
            ? string(data.begin(), data.begin() + n)
            : data;
    }

protected:
    int_type underflow() override
    {
        auto result = sbuf.sbumpc();
        data.clear();
        data.push_back(static_cast<char_type>(result));
        setg(data.data(), data.data(), data.data() + 1);
        return result;
    }
};
```

Client interface is slightly changed, as we now take a reference - `peekbuf buf{*std::cin.rdbuf()};`.